# Using streamwriter but file is always empty

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm using Streamwriter to save my list data to a text file, but the file is always empty when I open it.
I can get the list to display all of the inputs, so the list works. Heres the code for the filewriter.

```
private void SaveToFile()
    {
        string taxpayerLine;
        string taxpayerFile;
        string myFileName;
        FileInfo myFile;
        SaveFileDialog taxpayerFileChooser;

        StreamWriter fileWriter;


        taxpayerFileChooser = new SaveFileDialog();
        taxpayerFileChooser.Filter = "All text files|*.txt";
        taxpayerFileChooser.ShowDialog();
        taxpayerFile = taxpayerFileChooser.FileName;
        taxpayerFileChooser.Dispose();

        fileWriter = new StreamWriter(taxpayerFile, true);

        foreach (Taxpayer tp in Taxpayers)
        {
            taxpayerLine = tp.Name + "," +
                tp.Salary.ToString() + "," +
                tp.InvestmentIncome.ToString() + "," +
                (tp.InvestmentIncome + tp.Salary).ToString() + "," +
                tp.GetRate().ToString() + "," +
                tp.GetTax().ToString();

            fileWriter.WriteLine(taxpayerLine);
        }

        fileWriter.Close();
        fileWriter.Dispose();

        myFile = new FileInfo(taxpayerFile);
        myFileName = myFile.Name;

        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved to " + myFileName);
    }
```

Comment: If you break-point the foreach is there anything in Taxpayers?

Comment: You should be using `using` statements for the disposable stuff. But assuming your code executes without any exceptions being thrown, the only way your file could be empty is if either you are looking at the wrong file, or the `Taxpayers` collection is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing your code like this:

```
private void SaveToFile()
{
    string taxpayerLine;
    string taxpayerFile = string.Empty;
    string myFileName;
    FileInfo myFile;

    using (SaveFileDialog taxpayerFileChooser = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        taxpayerFileChooser.Filter = "All text files|*.txt";
        if (DialogResult.OK == taxpayerFileChooser.ShowDialog())
        {
            taxpayerFile = taxpayerFileChooser.FileName;
        }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(taxpayerFile))
    {
        using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(taxpayerFile, true))
        {
            foreach (Taxpayer tp in Taxpayers)
            {
                taxpayerLine = tp.Name + "," +
                tp.Salary.ToString() + "," +
                tp.InvestmentIncome.ToString() + "," +
                (tp.InvestmentIncome + tp.Salary).ToString() + "," +
                tp.GetRate().ToString() + "," +
                tp.GetTax().ToString();

                fileWriter.WriteLine(taxpayerLine);
            }
        }

        myFile = new FileInfo(taxpayerFile);
        myFileName = myFile.Name;

        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved to " + myFileName);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data not saved");
    }
}
```

The using statement explicit calls the Dispose() method of disposable objects after the block execution. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: The code should handle that the user can press "Cancel" or close the dialog without choosing a file.

Comment: I modified my answer for extra check. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, thats better now.